# Char[] type to String in ATEasy

Tags: string, char, basic, ateasy

In the ATEasy software development environment, I have a `char[100]` which contains a sentence and I want to convert it to `String` type.
How can I do that? Is there a special function for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy.

I just assigned the char array variable to the string variable, as follows:

`sStringType = acCharType;`

and it worked.
I assume that an implicit casting is performed.